# Tidy GDP data of different cities in different years

Tags: r

I would like to tidy up my data (GDP billion dollars of different cities in different years):

```
year   york Syd ACT Mel
2016    236 231 234 254
2017    236 231 234 254
2018    236 231 234 254
2019    236 231 234 254
```

What I would like

```
city    year    gdp(billion dollar)
york    2016    236
    2017    236
        2018    236
        2019    236
Syd 2016    231
        2017    231
        2018    231
        2019    231
```

How can I do it? Are there any good functions or strategies to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pivot_longer()`:

```
dplyr::pivot_longer(df, -year, names_to = "city", values_to = "gdp")
```

Data:

```
df <- dplyr::tribble(
  ~year, ~york, ~Syd, ~ACT, ~Mel,
  2016, 236, 231, 234, 254,
  2017, 236, 231, 234, 254,
  2018, 236, 231, 234, 254,
  2019, 236, 231, 234, 254
)
```